# Is there such a thing as user defined constants simolar to user defined functions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with a VBA module containing lots of user defined functions that are extensively used by formulas in the different worksheets.

So I can write for example `=MyFunction(A1; A2; 5)`. This works well.

Now I'd like to have user defined constants so I could write:

```
=MyFunction(A1; A2; myConstant)
```

The only way I found to do this, is putting all my constants in named cells in a separate worksheet. This works well but it's awkward.

Another possibility is writing a user defined function for each constant such as:

```
Function myConstant()
    myConstant = 5
End Function
```

This is also awkward, and then the constants must be followed by `()`, e.g.

```
MyFunction(A1; A2; myConstant())
```

I tried to put the constants at the beginning of the module that contains by user defined functions:

```
Const myConstant As Integer = 5
```

but this only allows be to use the constants in VBA code, but not in Excel formulas.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put them in cells. You can define names that refer to values as well as ranges. Just put `=5` for example in the RefersTo part of the Name Manager.

Comment: This is still somewhat awkward. It would be cleaner to have those constants elsewhere than in the name manager, but I suppose that this is the best I can get. I'll accept your answer unless someone comes up with something better.

Comment: Where would not be awkward then, given that you cannot access VBA constants or document properties without additional UDFs?

Comment: Actually I have several workbooks using the same VBA module. Whenever the module changes, I have to import it in each and every worksbook, but with your solution I also have to maintain the names in each and every workbook.

Comment: It was a somewhat rhetorical question, since there are no other options. (I'm not sure why you aren't using an add-in for the code though) . Using UDFs to return the constants or code to create/update the names sounds simplest for this.